# how to create a generic custom model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I am running into problems where the default model binder keeps throwing ModelState errors for indirect fields. Consider the following :

```
    public class Model1 {
    public int Id;
    [Required]
    public string Name;
    [Required]
    public string Type;
}

public class Model2 {
    public int Id;
    [Required]
    public string Name;
    [Required]
    //selected via a dropdown consisting of all Model1 record names and Id for value
    public Model1 Model1;
    }
```

When creating/editing a Model2 entity in a typical controller, I should only get model state errors for Model2.Name and Model2.Model1 if I don't have any values for them. However, I also get errors for Model1.Type since I am not populating Model1.Type in this case since I don't need it. I am just populating a dropdown for Model1 and just populating Model1.Name.

How can I write a Custom Binder that is generic enough to say: Only validate direct fields/properties of the Model in question. In this case, only Model2.Model1 and Model2.Name should be validated.

Comment: I'm guessing this is your domain model.  For the purposes of the view,  Model2 only needs the Id of Model1 to be passed back to link the 2 entities.  consider creating a view model that models the needs of your view and not of your entire domain.

Comment: I would rather not create a View Model since I am using Telerik to populate/edit grids directly via Models.